# Convert flattr buttons to privacy friendly ones on the fly using Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, privacy

I know how to block flattr buttons using Adblock Plus but I'd like to use Flattr so blocking isn't a solution. However, Im concerned about the button sending a query to the flattr server even before I clicked it. So how can I convert the regular flattr button on any website to a privacy friendly one that uses only a local image or text?

I'm using Firefox.